# Android : How to get the total page loaded in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, progress

I'm working on a `WebView` with ProgressBar, i want to display the total page loaded in `TextView` as `(some_string + %)`, It should display the page loaded as `n%`. (n is the `int` for total page loaded). Anyway to do?

Comment: page is loaded from url or html(book) please clarify ?

Comment: Both are kinda same, But i'm talking about url here.

Answer (score 0):

Please see `WebChromeClient#onProgressChanged`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged%28android.webkit.WebView), int)